# ¿Cómo eliminar el preview de la imagen seleccionada en mi input file en Angular?

Tags: angular

Cuando el usuario elige una imagen en el `input file`, con esta funcion hago un preview de esa imagen:

```js
imgPreview: string | ArrayBuffer;

selectImage(event){
    if (event.target.files.length > 0){
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.image = file;
      // preview de la img
      const reader = new FileReader();
      // leo el archivo seleccionado
      reader.onload = e => this.imgPreview = reader.result;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

El problema esta en que, cuando hago el `submit`, el formulario se resetea, pero la imagen se sigue mostrando.

aca mi `input file`:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="createBook($event)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Imagen</label>
    <input type="file"               
    class="form-control" 
    name="image"
    formControlName="image" 
     multiple (change)="selectImage($event)">
    <div *ngIf="imgPreview != null" class="text-center my-2">
      <img [src]="imgPreview" class="img-fluid">
    </div>                           
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
       <button [disabled]="form.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block">Guardar</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block text-white" (click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>
  </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Y como reinicias el valor de `imgPreview`?

Comment: gracias Lobo, es cierto olvide poner this.imgPreview = null; en la funcion que se ejecuta al hacer el submit.